# Allocation vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have a vector of vector built in the following way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> symbols;
```

I want to insert some int in the structure. To do this, I want to check that the position in which the int will be inserted is legal. I'm trying to make the vector growing up in a dynamic way. 
For this reason, I wrote the following code:

```
void checkIndex(unsigned int i0, unsigned int i1) {
int mult_fac=2;
if(i0>=symbols.capacity()-1){
    symbols.reserve((i0+1)*mult_fac);

}
if(i1>=symbols[i0].capacity()-1){
    symbols[i0].reserve((i1 + 1)*mult_fac);
}
```

}

To verify that all of this works, I wrote a main:

```
int main() {

for(;;){
    int i=rand()%1000;
    int j=rand()%1000;
    checkIndex(i,j);
}
return 0;}
```

But, the output shows a bad memory access:

> "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

I'm using Windows 10. 
I can't understand how to fix it! 
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `reserve` only allocates space, it doesn't create objects in the vector. Therefore you cannot access `symbols[i0]` if there is no object at that index

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problems are that `capacity()` doesn't tell you the size of the vector, you need `size()` instead and that `reserve()` doesn't change the size of the vector, you need `resize()` instead.

Finally your tests are too pessimistic, after changing `caapcity` for `size` you could just have

```
if (i0 >= symbols.size()) {
```

and

```
if (i1 >= symbols[i0].size()) {
```

You don't need the `-1` in there, an index is invalid if it is >= to the size.

Comment: What did you read there that made you not use it? If you want to resize your vector it's the obvious thing to use.

Comment: I didn't use the resize, because I've read on the cpp reference that: 
If the current size is greater than count, where count is the argument of the resize method, the container is reduced to its first count elements: [link] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: @Martina_bxxu But the current size cannot be greater than the count `if (i0 >= symbols.size()) {` prevents that. The vector is only growing.